# Ignore push notifications when iOS app is in the foreground

Tags: ios, debugging, apple-push-notifications

I have a fairly large iOS project. When the app receives a notifications while in the foreground, the notification is displayed in something that looks like an AlertView. I want to get rid of it. I have no idea if this is something I programmed myself a long time ago, or if one of the frameworks in the project (Parse, Onesignal, FBSDK) is doing this. My question is, how can I find out where that alert view is coming from, so I can remove that code. I have not implemented the `willPresentNotification` method anywhere (I have searched through the entire project). I do have a `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method, and even though that should only be called when a notification is tapped, I have tried commenting it out. I have also searched through the entire project for UIAlertView and UIAlertController, to no avail.

Comment: Notification received in `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method when application in foreground, so show your code of this method for more help.

Comment: I have removed the method completely, and I'm still getting notifications while app is in the foreground. Is there a way to get a hold of the UIAlertView / UIAlertControl object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OneSignal SDK](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup) automatically uses the new [UserNotifications Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications), when iOS10 is detected on device.

In this case, the AppDelegate method [didReceiveRemoteNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application?language=objc) method not get called, instead methods in [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate?preferredLanguage=occ) get invoked, which is captured by SDK to record clicks/views.

OneSignal use [callback](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-native-sdk#section--oshandlenotificationreceivedblock-) to handle received Notification.

- OSHandleNotificationReceivedBlock: Called when the app receives a notification while in focus only
- OSHandleNotificationActionBlock: Called when the user opens or taps an action on a notification.
- OSNotificationOpenedResult: The information returned from a notification the user received.

You can directly implement [UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate?preferredLanguage=occ) methods to handling notification-related interactions in your app.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. This one line solved the problem: `OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayTypeNone;`