# ios show me a uialertcontroller with received Notification info

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

I write a app in `objective-c` language. I have problem with received notification (i used oneSignal service).
when i send a notification to my app, if app state be active, then you see this (information that sent with the notification):

[image]

(this is a test app. and not real app. so sorry for this UI :)  )

anyway, i implement this app with the same code of my another app that work without any problem but in this app i faced with this problem ..

i think problem is with apple push notification service certificate.
but if you think the problem is different, please help me ...
thanks .

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif
@interface AppDelegate ()<UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [FIRApp configure];

    [OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions appId:@"fc0695b4-3a0d-4cd3-882d-00ebdba6729f"];



    NSDictionary *remoteNotificationPayload = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (remoteNotificationPayload) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notification" object:nil userInfo:remoteNotificationPayload];
    }


    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];



    //    // Register for remote notifications. This shows a permission dialog on first run, to
    //    // show the dialog at a more appropriate time move this registration accordingly.
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
        NSLog(@"ios 7;");
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ios 8");
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UNAuthorizationOptions allNotificationTypes =
            (UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionNone | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationType)allNotificationTypes categories:nil];



            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {
            // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            NSLog(@"ios 10");
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionNone
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            }];
            [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter].delegate = self;
#endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }





    return YES;
}


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification %@", userInfo);

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        // Nothing to do if applicationState is Inactive, the iOS already displayed an alert view.
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Did receive a Remote Notification" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your App name received this notification while it was running:\n%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"]]delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
    // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
    // TODO: Handle data of notification

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"didReceiveRemoteNotification %@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
// [END receive_message]

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
// Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
       willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions))completionHandler {
#define ROOTVIEW [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController]
    // Print message ID.
    NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo;
    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"willPresentNotification %@", userInfo);


    NSDictionary *dic = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSDictionary *dic2 = [dic objectForKey:@"alert"];

    if ([[dic2 objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"new-order"]) {

        NSError *eror = nil;
        NSString *body = [dic2 objectForKey:@"body"];
        NSData *data = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *dict3 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&eror];
        NSLog(@"dict3 i s:%@",dict3);
    }else if([[dic2 objectForKey:@"title"] isEqualToString:@"order-canceled"]){



    }





    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    //    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionNone);
}








// Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response
         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;

    // Print full message.
    NSLog(@"didReceiveNotificationResponse %@", userInfo);
    completionHandler();
}
#endif



- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Unable to register for remote notifications: %@", error);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"gereftam");
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSString *iosVersion = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];

    NSLog(@"APNs token retrieved: %@", deviceToken);
    NSString *str = [@"~/Documents/deviceToken.txt" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"token is :%@",token);
    NSDictionary *devicetoken = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    devicetoken = @{
                    @"token":token,
                    @"iosVersion":iosVersion
                    };


    [devicetoken writeToFile:str atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: what is your issue?? if alert is your issue then this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49249101/1042817

Comment: From your question it is not possible to know what your problem is? Is the problem that alert is being shown or that alert and notifications are not being received by the app? If the later than you have a problem with push notification certificates or you are using simulator for testing...

Comment: @Rocky thank you ... you save my day ...